# ways of parameter passing

Tags: parameters

what is the difference between all of these passing parameters

1). value
2). reference
3).pure reference
4) value result, evaluation of parameters only on subroutine entry
5). value result, evaluation of parameters on subroutine entry and exit

I have the following function written in a (FORTRAN)-like pseudo code

```
DIMENTION X(2)
I=2
X(1) = 10
X(2) = 20
CALL SUB (I, X(I))


SUBROUTINE SUB (A, B)
A = 1
B = 30
RETURN 
END
```

I want to know what going to happen to the I, X(1), X(2) after passing values with conditions described above.

Comment: you cannot try to run it, because every compiler has a different ways of passing the parameters. and i need to know how exactly each of this ways works. I doubt i will find 5 different compilers for the Fortran with each of those requirements

Comment: the problem is i need to know how it works behind the scenes. i don't really need the actual answers.

Comment: @lejadina: Why exactly do you need to know this? As Mark says, Fortran only gives you tools like `intent` and `value` attributes, and no direct control over argument association like C `int *x` / `int x`. You would probably need to look at disassembled code to figure this out, and it could be specific to your compiler.

Comment: I am taking Programming Languages course in school which requires us to know this theory, i missed a class and don't get what's flying. This is not for the fortran, i have fortran code as an example. i need the actual theory of what gets modified and when.

Comment: This is an example of bad code, expensive to maintain, and hard to predict what would happen.  I would GUESS that if you tricked a compiler into compiling this (so, the main routine couldn't validate against the interface of the subroutine), then in your main body, `I=1`, and `X(2) = 30`.  (As I suspect the address of X(2) was sent, rather than X(I) where I is then set to 1, etc).  This is of course only a guess. @HighPerformanceMark gave the best suggestion of actually trying it to see.

Comment: @lejadina Oh... so your question is more like: **IF** these arguments were to be passed by value, reference, etc., what would happen during execution? If so, an example in pseudocode would have been a lot clearer, since the suggestion that this is Fortran is, as you can see, extremely confusing.

Comment: exactly! you got me, man! sorry didn't mean to be confusing, i posted this as an example only because we had it in class. but u can still consider it a pheudocode

Comment: @lejadina: I understand the example is not your fault, it's just hard to interpret for Fortran programmers, who are drawn here by the [fortran] tag (it repels many others ;-). That's why I would not use it even as an example or EVER suggest anyone to write Fortran in this fashion.

Comment: Now I understand a little better.  I've edited the question in light of OP's comments.